# How to know hbase server is running or not

Tags: hbase

I am new to Hbase. 
I have to trigger an email when hbase goes down on the cluster.
Command `sudo -u hbase jps` gives the process of hbase.

Please suggest on how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a shell script to run on schedule. 
This script will trigger jps command on path \hbase\bin .
Your shell script will start with something like this: 
jps > something.txt
....
....

Place a check in the script i.e. if the result of this jps command returns HMaster & HRegionServer process names then it means HBase is not down. In case any of the process is missing then HBase is down, hence you can trigger mail through your script.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. I am using java and checking the jps cmd.